# How can I pass a set of an unknown number of arguments to a function in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, arguments

When you have a function that takes a variable amount of arguments (like ndgrid), how can you pass an arbitrary list of arguments to that function?

For example I want to make it so that sometimes I pass two vectors to ndgrid and get out two matrices, i.e.,

```
[X1,X2] = ndgrid(x1,x2);
```

But other times I might have more X's, so I'll want

```
[X1,X2,X3,X4] = ndgrid(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

1. Is there any kind of structure I can use to store a list of an unknown number of arguments and then just give that list to a function? And,
2. Is there a way to retrieve all of the outputs from a function, when you don't know how many there will be?

Comment: a quick and dirty way would be to abstract your input and output up a level ("dimension") and take an array of inputs and output an array - that is [X] = ndgrid(x) where X and x are cell arrays or something, with each element an actual input element

Comment: I am not well-versed enough, however, to state definitively if MATLAB has a `varargs` type functionality (I'm sure it does as it can compile into C)

Comment: oh it's remarkably simple: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

Comment: FWIW, this is a different question than the current marked duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5215244/931379). That question asks how to create a new function with multiple inputs/outputs; the answer is varargin/varargout. This question is really how to programmatically use such a function with an unknown number of arguments.

Answer (score 7):

To pass in a variable number of inputs to an existing function, use cell arrays with expansion, like this:

```
x = 1:10;
y = randn(size(x));
plotArguments = {'color' 'red' 'linestyle' '-'};
plot(x, y, plotArguments{:});
```

or

```
plotArguments = {1:10 randn(1,10)  'color' 'red' 'linestyle' '-'};
plot(plotArguments{:});
```

You can use the same trick to receive multiple numbers of outputs.  The only hard part is remembering the correct notations.

```
numArgumentsToAccept = 2;
[results{1:numArgumentsToAccept }] = max(randn(100,1));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured it had something to do with cell arrays, but I didn't know the notation.

Answer (score 4):

Using `varargin`,`nargin`, `varargout` and `nargout` you can easily define variable argument/output functions. See the attached MATLAB documentation link for the varargin page. The others are linked at the bottom:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

EDIT: BTW, not to toot my own horn, but it seems to be implemented just as I had suggested in the "quick-and-dirty" comment hehehe

Comment: This doesn't address the question of passing a variable number of segregated arguments into a pre-existing function. sub2ind() for example of the example of ngrid as given in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

a function that returns all arguments as outputs:

```
function varargout = ndgrid(varargin)    
    varargout = varargin;
return
```