# MATLAB: Is there a method to better organize functions for experiments?

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, function-parameter

I will run a set of experiments. The main method evaluated has the following signature:

```
[Model threshold] = detect(...
    TrainNeg, TrainPos, nf, nT, factors, ...
    removeEachStage, applyEstEachStage, removeFeatures);
```

where `removeEachStage`, `applyEstEachStage`, and `removeFeatures` are booleans. You can see that if I reverse the order of any of these boolean parameters I may get wrong results.

Is there a method in MATLAB that allows better organization in order to minimize this kind of error? Or is there any tool I can use to protect me against these errors?

Comment: you might find some of the answers from here useful: [How to deal with name/value pairs of function arguments in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2775263/97160)

Comment: check out `parseArgs` on the file exchange. I use it every day: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10670-parseargs-simplifies-input-processing-for-functions-with-multiple-options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Organization with a struct**

You could input a `struct` that has these parameters as it's fields.

For example a structure with fields

```
setts.TrainNeg
     .TrainPos
     .nf
     .nT
     .factors
     .removeEachStage
     .applyEstEachStage
     .removeFeatures
```

That way when you set the fields it is clear what the field is, unlike a function call where you have to remember the order of the parameters.

Then your function call becomes

```
[Model threshold] = detect(setts);
```

and your function definition would be something like

```
function [model, threshold] = detect(setts)
```

Then simply replace the occurrences of e.g. `param` with `setts.param`.

**Mixed approach**

You can also mix this approach with your current one if you prefer, e.g.

```
[Model threshold] = detect(in1, in2, setts);
```

if you wanted to still explicitly include `in1` and `in2`, and bundle the rest into `setts`.

**OOP approach**

Another option is to turn detect into a class. The benefit to this is that a `detect` object would then have member variables with fixed names, as opposed to structs where if you make a typo when setting a field you just create a new field with the misspelled name.

For example

```
classdef detect()
properties
  TrainNeg = [];
  TrainPos  = [];
  nf = [];
  nT = [];
  factors = [];
  removeEachStage = [];
  applyEstEachStage = [];
  removeFeatures =[];
end
methods
  function run(self)
    % Put the old detect code in here, use e.g. self.TrainNeg to access member variables (aka properties)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is very clear. I've found the solution through OOP very interesting. Also, I think the [amount of overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1745686/957997) added does not make much difference.