# InputParser vs exist(...,'var') vs nargin performance

Tags: performance, matlab

Is there any performance comparison among those three variants for input checking/default initializaion?

It would be useful a comparison on a recent version e.g. R2014b and and older one R2012b.

An example:

```
function foo(a,b)
  if nargin < 1, a = 1; end
  if nargin < 2, b = 2; end
end

versus

function foo(a,b)
  if exist('a','var'), a = 1; end
  if exist('b','var'), b = 2; end
end

versus 

function foo(varargin)
  p = inputParser;
  addOptional(p,'a',1)
  addOptional(p,'b',2)
  parse(p,varargin{:})
end
```

Using Amro's testing suite, on R2014b:

```
  func           nargs       time   
_________________    _____    __________
'foo_nargin'         0        2.3674e-05
'foo_exist'          0        3.1339e-05
'foo_inputparser'    0        9.6934e-05
'foo_nargin'         1        2.4437e-05
'foo_exist'          1        3.2157e-05
'foo_inputparser'    1         0.0001307
'foo_nargin'         2        2.3838e-05
'foo_exist'          2        3.0492e-05
'foo_inputparser'    2        0.00015775
```

Comment: I haven't done any benchmarks, but I suspect the first option would be the fastest. Also for this simple case of optional positional arguments, that's the easiest way to implement it (of course `inputParser` is more flexible and handles more cases). Personally I don't like the style of the second method (`exist`).

Comment: @Amro: is there a particular reason why you dislike the `exist`? Of course it's a matter of taste, but I tend to prefer it over `nargin` because of the expresiveness.

Comment: @Egon: no reason really, I just find it cleaner not to hard-code the variable names. When refactoring, it is more likely that you will rename a variable than it is to move its position in the arguments list. With `exist` the variable name is specified as a string, so you might miss it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code to test the three approaches:

```
function t = testArgParsing()
    args = {1, 2};
    fcns = {
        @foo_nargin ;
        @foo_exist ;
        @foo_inputparser
    };

    % parameters sweep
    [f,k] = ndgrid(1:numel(fcns), 0:numel(args));
    f = f(:); k = k(:);

    % test combinations of functions and number of input args
    t = cell(numel(f), 3);
    for i=1:size(t,1)
        t{i,1} = func2str(fcns{f(i)});
        t{i,2} = k(i);
        t{i,3} = timeit(@() feval(fcns{f(i)}, args{1:k(i)}), 2);
    end

    % format results in table
    t = cell2table(t, 'VariableNames',{'func','nargs','time'});
end

function [aa,bb] = foo_nargin(a,b)
  if nargin < 1, a = 1; end
  if nargin < 2, b = 2; end
  aa = a;
  bb = b;
end

function [aa,bb] = foo_exist(a,b)
  if ~exist('a','var'), a = 1; end
  if ~exist('b','var'), b = 2; end
  aa = a;
  bb = b;
end

function [aa,bb] = foo_inputparser(varargin)
  p = inputParser;
  addOptional(p,'a',1);
  addOptional(p,'b',2);
  parse(p, varargin{:});
  aa = p.Results.a;
  bb = p.Results.b;
end
```

Here is what I get in R2014a on my machine:

```
>> t = testArgParsing
t = 
          func           nargs       time   
    _________________    _____    __________
    'foo_nargin'         0        3.4556e-05
    'foo_exist'          0        5.2901e-05
    'foo_inputparser'    0        0.00010254
    'foo_nargin'         1        2.5531e-05
    'foo_exist'          1        3.7105e-05
    'foo_inputparser'    1         0.0001263
    'foo_nargin'         2        2.4991e-05
    'foo_exist'          2        3.6772e-05
    'foo_inputparser'    2        0.00015148
```

And a pretty plot to view the results:

```
tt = unstack(t, 'time', 'func');
names = tt.Properties.VariableNames(2:end);
bar(tt{:,2:end}.')
set(gca, 'XTick',1:numel(names), 'XTickLabel',names, 'YGrid','on')
legend(num2str(tt{:,1}, 'nargin=%d'))
ylabel('Time [sec]'), xlabel('Functions')
```

[image: report]

Comment: note that for such a short lived task, there are wide variations between different runs.. So maybe increase the number of arguments in the functions and make them more complex (maybe use large matrices as arguments)

Comment: I was thinking that `exist` should depend on the length of the variable names and the number of variables in th workspace. However, the test case for input initialization is usually always at the beginning of the function, much before any other variables start cluttering the workspace. So, it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: @OlegKomarov: right. `exist` will be probably be checking an internal lookup table of variable names, such an operation will always be slower than doing a simple less-than test on `nargin`

Comment: Upvoted, but downvoted again because that pink window border burnt my eyes.

Comment: @SamRoberts: haha, not my fault :) Windows automatically pickd a color to match a rotating desktop wallpaper. I guess the pic had a pink flower in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-ran Amro's test on 2023b with some changes:

- Added functions using Function Argument Validation introduced in 2019b
- Added more optional input arguments
- Removed function output assignments
- Run timeit on the function call 5000 times
- Added a variation with inputParser where p.Results is pulled out of the nested struct before accessing the values.

[Time Comparison Bar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv2OQ.png)

```matlab
function t = testArgParsing()
args = {0, 2, 5, 10, 15};
fcns = {
    @foo_nargin ;
    @foo_exist ;
    @foo_inputparser ;
    @foo_inputparser_struct ;
    @foo_argument ;
    @foo_argument_opt ;
};

% parameters sweep
[f,k] = ndgrid(1:numel(fcns), cell2mat(args));
f = f(:); k = k(:);
% test combinations of functions and number of input args
t = cell(numel(f), 3);
for i=1:size(t,1)
    t{i,1} = func2str(fcns{f(i)});
    t{i,2} = k(i);
    if isequal(fcns{f(i)}, @foo_argument_opt)
        if k(i) >= 0; opt = struct; end
        if k(i) >= 1; opt.a01 = 1; end
        if k(i) >= 2; opt.a02 = 2; end
        if k(i) >= 3; opt.a03 = 3; end
        if k(i) >= 4; opt.a04 = 4; end
        if k(i) >= 5; opt.a05 = 5; end
        if k(i) >= 6; opt.a06 = 6; end
        if k(i) >= 7; opt.a07 = 7; end
        if k(i) >= 8; opt.a08 = 8; end
        if k(i) >= 9; opt.a09 = 9; end
        if k(i) >= 10; opt.a10 = 10; end
        if k(i) >= 11; opt.a11 = 11; end
        if k(i) >= 12; opt.a12 = 12; end
        if k(i) >= 13; opt.a13 = 13; end
        if k(i) >= 14; opt.a14 = 14; end
        if k(i) >= 15; opt.a15 = 15; end
        cellArgs = namedargs2cell(opt);
    else
        cellArgs = num2cell(1:k(i));
    end
    t{i,3} = timeit(@() foo_nrun(fcns{f(i)}, cellArgs));
end
% format results in table
t = cell2table(t, 'VariableNames',{'func','nargs','time'});
end

function foo_nrun(fcn,cellArgs)
    nrun = 5000;
    for i = 1:nrun
        feval(fcn, cellArgs{:});
    end
end

function foo_nargin(a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15)
if nargin < 1, a01 = 1; end
if nargin < 2, a02 = 2; end
if nargin < 3, a03 = 3; end
if nargin < 4, a04 = 4; end
if nargin < 5, a05 = 5; end
if nargin < 6, a06 = 6; end
if nargin < 7, a07 = 7; end
if nargin < 8, a08 = 8; end
if nargin < 9, a09 = 9; end
if nargin < 10, a10 = 10; end
if nargin < 11, a11 = 11; end
if nargin < 12, a12 = 12; end
if nargin < 13, a13 = 13; end
if nargin < 14, a14 = 14; end
if nargin < 15, a15 = 15; end
a01;
a02;
a03;
a04;
a05;
a06;
a07;
a08;
a09;
a10;
a11;
a12;
a13;
a14;
a15;
end

function foo_exist(a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15)
if ~exist('a01','var'), a01 = 1; end
if ~exist('a02','var'), a02 = 2; end
if ~exist('a03','var'), a03 = 3; end
if ~exist('a04','var'), a04 = 4; end
if ~exist('a05','var'), a05 = 5; end
if ~exist('a06','var'), a06 = 6; end
if ~exist('a07','var'), a07 = 7; end
if ~exist('a08','var'), a08 = 8; end
if ~exist('a09','var'), a09 = 9; end
if ~exist('a10','var'), a10 = 10; end
if ~exist('a11','var'), a11 = 11; end
if ~exist('a12','var'), a12 = 12; end
if ~exist('a13','var'), a13 = 13; end
if ~exist('a14','var'), a14 = 14; end
if ~exist('a15','var'), a15 = 15; end
a01;
a02;
a03;
a04;
a05;
a06;
a07;
a08;
a09;
a10;
a11;
a12;
a13;
a14;
a15;
end

function foo_inputparser(varargin)
p = inputParser;
addOptional(p,'a01',1);
addOptional(p,'a02',2);
addOptional(p,'a03',3);
addOptional(p,'a04',4);
addOptional(p,'a05',5);
addOptional(p,'a06',6);
addOptional(p,'a07',7);
addOptional(p,'a08',8);
addOptional(p,'a09',9);
addOptional(p,'a10',10);
addOptional(p,'a11',11);
addOptional(p,'a12',12);
addOptional(p,'a13',13);
addOptional(p,'a14',14);
addOptional(p,'a15',15);
parse(p, varargin{:});
p.Results.a01;
p.Results.a02;
p.Results.a03;
p.Results.a04;
p.Results.a05;
p.Results.a06;
p.Results.a07;
p.Results.a08;
p.Results.a09;
p.Results.a10;
p.Results.a11;
p.Results.a12;
p.Results.a13;
p.Results.a14;
p.Results.a15;

end

function foo_inputparser_struct(varargin)
p = inputParser;
addOptional(p,'a01',1);
addOptional(p,'a02',2);
addOptional(p,'a03',3);
addOptional(p,'a04',4);
addOptional(p,'a05',5);
addOptional(p,'a06',6);
addOptional(p,'a07',7);
addOptional(p,'a08',8);
addOptional(p,'a09',9);
addOptional(p,'a10',10);
addOptional(p,'a11',11);
addOptional(p,'a12',12);
addOptional(p,'a13',13);
addOptional(p,'a14',14);
addOptional(p,'a15',15);
parse(p, varargin{:});
tmp = p.Results;
tmp.a01;
tmp.a02;
tmp.a03;
tmp.a04;
tmp.a05;
tmp.a06;
tmp.a07;
tmp.a08;
tmp.a09;
tmp.a10;
tmp.a11;
tmp.a12;
tmp.a13;
tmp.a14;
tmp.a15;
end

function foo_argument(a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15)
arguments
    a01 = 1
    a02 = 2
    a03 = 3
    a04 = 4
    a05 = 5
    a06 = 6
    a07 = 7
    a08 = 8
    a09 = 9
    a10 = 10
    a11 = 11
    a12 = 12
    a13 = 13
    a14 = 14
    a15 = 15
end
a01;
a02;
a03;
a04;
a05;
a06;
a07;
a08;
a09;
a10;
a11;
a12;
a13;
a14;
a15;
end

function foo_argument_opt(opt)
arguments
    opt.a01 = 1
    opt.a02 = 2
    opt.a03 = 3
    opt.a04 = 4
    opt.a05 = 5
    opt.a06 = 6
    opt.a07 = 7
    opt.a08 = 8
    opt.a09 = 9
    opt.a10 = 10
    opt.a11 = 11
    opt.a12 = 12
    opt.a13 = 13
    opt.a14 = 14
    opt.a15 = 15
end
opt.a01;
opt.a02;
opt.a03;
opt.a04;
opt.a05;
opt.a06;
opt.a07;
opt.a08;
opt.a09;
opt.a10;
opt.a11;
opt.a12;
opt.a13;
opt.a14;
opt.a15;
end
```

```matlab
t = testArgParsing()

tt = unstack(t, 'time', 'func');
names = tt.Properties.VariableNames(2:end);
bar(tt{:,2:end}.')
set(gca, 'XTick',1:numel(names), 'XTickLabel',names, 'YGrid','on','TickLabelInterpreter','None')
legend(num2str(tt{:,1}, 'nargin=%d'),'Location','northwest')
ylabel('Time [sec]'), xlabel('Functions')
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')
```

```matlab
t =

  30×3 table

               func               nargs       time   
    __________________________    _____    __________

    {'foo_nargin'            }      0      0.00033001
    {'foo_exist'             }      0         0.08243
    {'foo_inputparser'       }      0          0.5845
    {'foo_inputparser_struct'}      0         0.21552
    {'foo_argument'          }      0      0.00050585
    {'foo_argument_opt'      }      0        0.027147
    {'foo_nargin'            }      2      0.00058672
    {'foo_exist'             }      2        0.083175
    {'foo_inputparser'       }      2         0.55961
    {'foo_inputparser_struct'}      2          0.2141
    {'foo_argument'          }      2      0.00056622
    {'foo_argument_opt'      }      2        0.035206
    {'foo_nargin'            }      5      0.00072787
    {'foo_exist'             }      5        0.083359
    {'foo_inputparser'       }      5         0.58168
    {'foo_inputparser_struct'}      5         0.22248
    {'foo_argument'          }      5      0.00074445
    {'foo_argument_opt'      }      5        0.047712
    {'foo_nargin'            }     10       0.0010616
    {'foo_exist'             }     10        0.083944
    {'foo_inputparser'       }     10         0.58553
    {'foo_inputparser_struct'}     10         0.23748
    {'foo_argument'          }     10       0.0011567
    {'foo_argument_opt'      }     10        0.077103
    {'foo_nargin'            }     15       0.0013069
    {'foo_exist'             }     15        0.083586
    {'foo_inputparser'       }     15         0.60135
    {'foo_inputparser_struct'}     15         0.25337
    {'foo_argument'          }     15       0.0013697
    {'foo_argument_opt'      }     15        0.095364
```

Comment: `timeit` already runs the operation many times to get a good estimate of cost. And it subtracts the cost of the function handle call and looping and so on. Your timings now include the overhead of looping and calling `feval`.

Comment: `timeit` returns a warning that the measured times may be inaccurate when the functions are called only once because of how fast it's running. For some single function calls, I'm getting even 0 seconds returned. All tests include overhead of the looping and `feval`, so a relative performance comparison seems fair to me. The only difference in overhead is with the `@foo_argument_opt` which requires both names and values in the argument inputs, but this additional overhead isn't artificial since a name-value input is required for argument validation with structs.